# Unexpected(?) behavior of reusable React hook functions or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to write my own reusable useEffect hook function `useEffectOnce()` to run only once (on mount and unmount), but it seems impossible. My function is called after every re-render: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjx452lvox

```
function useEffectOnce() {
  console.log("I am in useEffectOnce");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am in useEffectOnce's useEffect");
    return () => {
      console.log("i am leaving useEffectOnce's useEffect");
    };
  }, []);
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffectOnce(); // once!?

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h3>useEffectOnce (my reusable function)... Wait, once!?</h3>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        You clicked me {count} times
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Notes:**

- useEffect() hook inside useEffectOnce() works as expected
- `useEffectOnce(() => {}, []);` changes nothing

... and then big surprise, same behavior with reusable useState hook function(!?): https://codesandbox.io/s/2145m37xnr

My function `useButton` is called after every re-render, and when is first, independent, button clicked.

```
function useButton(initialCounterValue) {
  const [usebuttoncount, setUseButtonCount] = useState(initialCounterValue);

  console.log("I am in useButton");

  const handleuseButtonClick = () => {
    setUseButtonCount(usebuttoncount + 1);
  };

  return {
    usebuttoncount,
    onClick: handleuseButtonClick
  };
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const useButtonCounter = useButton(0);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h3>
        useButton (my reusable useState function) is called only when... OMG!?
      </h3>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        You clicked me {count} times
      </button>
      <br />
      <button {...useButtonCounter}>
        (useButton hook) You clicked me {useButtonCounter.usebuttoncount} times
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Custom hooks are nothing but normal function that contains hooks, and the reason that they need to use the `use` prefix is that you have have linting on it, so that you accidently don't use your custom functions which contain hooks at random places rather than at the top of the component as hooks are supposed to be.

You call your custom hooks in the component which leads to the actual react hooks to be defined, evaluated and executed. A custom hooks cannot have the same functionality as the original hooks since React has custom logic to evaluate them

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Actually, custom hook can have same functionality - by wrapping built-in hook.

Comment: @estus, sure custom hooks can have some functionality but what I mean is that they cannot be treated like the predefined hooks. Predefined hooks behave in some way like useEffect calls the internal function based on the second argument its passed, a custom hook will be called always on render unless you provide a useMemo or other wrappers with it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I mean `useEffectWrapper(...args => useEffect(...args))`. It does exactly same thing. All hooks are always called on render. But built-in hooks are able to maintain internal state between calls while regular functions aren't.

Comment: @estus, I get you point and thats exactly what I wanted to communicate as well :-)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri That's my point. Can these functions be called Hooks? By 'old school' no. These are, really, internal React Hooks, but currently, these are like a bone thrown to dogs. Let's take some time... (except Additional Hooks, e.g. useReducer)

Comment: Guys, sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffectOnce` and `useButton` are regular functions. They are expected to run on every component render. When component function is called, there's no way to prevent them from being called by conventional JavaScript means (i.e. with no `eval`).

It's `useEffect` callback function (`I am in useEffectOnce's useEffect` log entry) that is expected to be called once on component mount. All code that needs to be evaluated on component mount should reside there.

Comment: 'Regular functions'. Why then 'A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks' in docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html ? Why then 'useButton' can't be 'myButton'?

Comment: It can. But `use` prefix is the convention. It's supposed to indicate that a function is custom hook.

Comment: Ok then... if that (please use 'use' prefix because we couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to hooks inside of it) approach satisfies you... I think custom hooks with 'use' prefix will be 'real hooks' in future, not just 'regular functions'.

Comment: I don't think that my own satisfaction is relevant. I guess you miss the point on hooks. What you're suggesting is impossible because of reasons explained in the answer; this is the limitation of JS. It is the use of built-in 'magic' hooks that makes custom hooks 'magic', not function name. Custom hooks are intended to combine and reuse built-in hooks.